# My docker container isn't starting on localhost (0.0.0.0) on Docker for Windows (Native using Hyper-V)

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm following [Digital Ocean's tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-nginx-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to start a nginx docker container (Currently on Step 4). Currently this is their output:

```
$ docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx
d3ccb73a91985651ec61231bca9f9c716f0dec807e354a29eeef2144f883a01c

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
b91f3ce26553        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   docker-nginx
```

But when I run it, this is my output (noticed the different IP of the container):

```
C:\>docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 -d nginx
d3ccb73a91985651ec61231bca9f9c716f0dec807e354a29eeef2144f883a01c

C:\>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
d3ccb73a9198        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   14 hours ago        Up 2 seconds        10.0.75.2:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   docker-nginx
```

Why does this happen? And how can I get the same results as Digital Ocean's? (Getting the server to start on localhost)

---

**Edit**: I'm using [Docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) (recently released) which apparently runs native using Hyper-V. My output for `docker-machine ls` is this:

```
C:\>docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

C:\>
```

Comment: Could you tell us about your environment? windows? linux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But when I run it, this is my output (noticed the different IP of the
>   container)

Since this a Windows machine, I assume that you're using <del>Docker Toolbox</del> Docker for Windows. `10.0.75.2` is the IP of the <del>`boot2docker`</del> virtual machine.

If you are using Windows or Mac OS, you will need some form of virtualization in
order to run Docker. The IP you just saw is the IP of that lightweight virtual machine.

> And how can I get the same results as Digital Ocean's? (Getting the
>   server to start on localhost)

Use a Linux distribution! Also you can enable *Expose container ports on `localhost` in [Docker For Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)* Settings:

[image]

Comment: I'm using docker for windows which runs native using hyper-V, check my updated description on the question

Comment: @sgarcia Go to Docker Settings > Network  and check `Expose container ports on localhost` and Restart

Comment: Please post this comment as an answer or edit your answer with this @Ali so I can mark it as correct, because this fixed it!

Answer (score 9):

Despite you created the containers in your local machine. These are actually running on a different machine (a virtual machine)

First, check what is the IP of your docker machine (the virtual machine)

```
$docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100
```

Then run `curl` command (or open a browser) to view the default web site on your `nginx` web server inside the container

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:80
```

Comment: I'm using docker for windows which runs native using hyper-V, check my updated description on the question. I don't have any docker machines running according to `docker-machine ls`, but all cohtainers run just fine

Comment: In docker for windows there is not virtualization, according with this doc (https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/) you should open a browser an type `http://docker`

Comment: Docker is all about running *Linux Containers* (Except for Windows Server 2016 case) and Windows does not ship with a linux. So Docker for Windows brings its own linux in a *Virtualized Form*. Virtualization is still there but in a  more seamless and less painful form.

Comment: Man you saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a virtual machine on windows:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

https://docs.docker.com/machine/concepts/

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this command for the first time: `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name docker-tutorial docker101tutorial`

I got this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name
> "/docker-tutorial" is already in use by container "LONG_CONTAINER_ID".
> You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
> name.

so, I tried to remove this container using: `docker rm -f LONG_CONTAINER_ID`

then I did: `docker run -d -p 3080:80 --name docker-tutorial docker101tutorial`

note **3080:80** instead of **80:80**... Had I run this from the docker desktop, I would see this default option below:

[image: options in docker desktop]